# redirection to cart and not home, after click on order history link of my order (prestashop 1.7

Tags: redirect, overriding, cart, prestashop-1.7

I work on prestashop 1.7.2.5.

In the order history, two links (detail & reorder) are available.

When I click on reorder, the items are added directly to the cart, but I am redirected to the homepage of the site ! I would like to be redirected to the cart directly. How can I change that? an override ?
Thanks for helping me !

Sofiane

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf6Au.jpg)

Comment: That's weird because the default behaviour is to redirect the customer to the order page. Can you check that you have this code `Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');` on line ~66 of controllers\front\OrderController.php ? Otherwise can you post the `postProcess()` function of this file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is on TODO.
You can follow this ticket: http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-5385.

Best regards, Khouloud

Answer (score 0):

Issue still on TODO but now on GitHub : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/9660